# much/little/less of+ noun

Tags: word-choice

I am having a little trouble in this structure in English:

1)It was really **more of** a comment than a question.

2)Jet travel has made moving from place to place **less of** an ordeal.

3)Getting tickets for Tuesday shouldn’t be **much of** a problem.

These are the examples of macmillian dictionary for much/little/less **of** sth

My question is this: Why is there "of" in these sentences?

Can it not be correct without "of" as in:
"It was really more a coment than a question"

For example, I typed "I am having a little trouble" instead of "little of a trouble"

I see the usage of "of" in these structures but I didn't get the hang of it.

Can you pls explain its sense there? Thank you very much

Comment: (1) Yes, you could say 'more a comment than a question'. As for (2) and (3), it's difficult to give a logical explanation other than 'that's how we say it'. You would describe travel as 'less difficult' (adjective) but 'less of an ordeal' (noun), but I can't think of a hard and fast rule.

Comment: I also can't give a hard or fast rule and I'm sure at least as many native speakers of British English would leave out the 'of' in all those examples. in 2) they might leave off the 'of' only if it was replaced by a suffix such as 'than it once was' but that's a different question.